# Passing params when using after_create method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have an application where a user adds a subscription and an account is automatically created for that subscription.  I also want to pass the current user to the account model as the account_manager.  So far I have:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
  after_create :create_account #after a subscription is created, automatically create an associated account

  def create_account
   Account.create :account_manager_id => "1" #need to modify this to get current user
  end
end



class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users 
  belongs_to :account_manager, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'account_manager_id'
  belongs_to :subscription, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

This works fine for the first user obviously but any attempts I've made to pass current_user, self, params, etc fails.  Also when I use the def method the subscription ID is no longer passed to the account.  I tried passing the current user through the AccountController but nothing happens.  In fact I can still create an account if my AccountController is completely blank.  Is after_create the best way to create an associated account and how do I pass the user to the account model?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using devise, you can do this directly in the controller with the current_user helper without a callback:

```
# subscriptions_controller.rb
def create
  ...
  if @subscription.save
    @subscription.create_account(account_manager: current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't use devise but this worked perfectly! THANK YOU!

Comment: shouldn't this action be written in a model level transaction? my understanding is that if you want to save/update data in more than one record, you would use a transaction